# How to export an Asp.net Pi chart graph into MS Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to export an Asp.net Pi chart graph into MS Excel?

I am using Asp.net,C#

Thank in advance
Rashed

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the Pi chart graph your using, and any relevant code which would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be to share the data source between the Asp.Net application and the Excel sheet.  Then on the data tab of Excel you could link to the same data source and base your graph on the same data.

[image]